# Python stomp upgrade to 8.0.1 causes SSL Library not found error

Tags: python, ssl, stomp

I've upgraded python stomp client from 7.0.0 to 8.0.1 and now an error message appears when attempting to connect to the queue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpsmqutils/mqlistener.py", line 64, in connect_and_subscribe
    conn.set_ssl([(_host, _port)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stomp/connect.py", line 68, in set_ssl
    self.transport.set_ssl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 859, in set_ssl
    raise Exception("SSL connection requested, but SSL library not found")
Exception: SSL connection requested, but SSL library not found
```

The error appears to be thrown in this part of the package code:
https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/blob/dev/stomp/transport.py#L843

Probably caused by update:
https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py/commit/624d904d0a595c9f2b0b67c082579c7c1ca2ab5b

**Questions**

- What updates do we need to make to our client connection code to get this working again?
- Do we need to pass in an option to set_ssl()?

**Code**

```
def connect_and_subscribe(conn, queue=_queue, sub_id=_sub_id):
    print(_hostname_prefix + "************************ MQUTILS MQLISTENER - CONNECT_AND_SUBSCRIBE *******************************")
    global _reconnect_attempts
    _reconnect_attempts = _reconnect_attempts + 1
    if _reconnect_attempts <= _max_attempts:
        # TODO: Retry timer with exponential backoff
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            if not os.getenv('MQ_DISABLE_SSL'):
                if _failback_host and _failback_port:
                    conn.set_ssl([(_host, _port),(_failback_host, _failback_port)])
                else:
                    conn.set_ssl([(_host, _port)])
            if not conn.is_connected():
                conn.connect(_user, _password, headers={'client-id': _client_id}, wait=True)
                print(f'{_hostname_prefix}connect_and_subscribe connecting {queue} to with connection id {sub_id} reconnect attempts: {_reconnect_attempts}', flush=True)
            else:
                print(f'{_hostname_prefix}connect_and_subscibe already connected {queue} to with connection id {sub_id} reconnect attempts {_reconnect_attempts}', flush=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(_hostname_prefix + 'Exception on disconnect. reconnecting...')
            print(_hostname_prefix + traceback.format_exc())
            connect_and_subscribe(conn)
        else:
            conn.subscribe(destination=queue, id=sub_id, ack='client-individual')
            _reconnect_attempts = 0
    else:
        print('{}Maximum reconnect attempts reached for this connection. reconnect attempts: {}'.format(_hostname_prefix, _reconnect_attempts), flush=True)
```

Comment: Looks like maybe your environment doesn't have the [`ssl`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#module-ssl) module that's expected to be there.

Answer (score 1):

We had to add the cryptography package in our environment to get this working correctly.